# How to check how long implementation time took

Tags: matlab, runtime

Is there a way in `matlab` (i.e; function) to check how long your program took to finish running?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the documentation for tic / toc functions.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the *profiler* too which will provide more data, and more food for thought, than plain old `tic` and `toc`.

Answer (score 4):

try running it with the profiler turned on, you'll get a breakdown of code performance so you can easily tell which areas are taking the longest....
sorry, misread the question...Yeah, tic-toc will do it!

Answer (score 3):

yes. [tic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) and [toc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toc.html):

```
tic;
# your code....
elapsed_time = toc;
```